# How to keep bottom outline (focus border) only?

Tags: html, css, border, outline

I'd like to remove left, right and up outlines, leaving only the bottom outline.

for example:

```
 input
_______
```

I know we can remove ALL outlines using this way:

`<input style="outline: none" >`

Is there any way to keep the bottom outline?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that. According to [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_outline.asp)

> Outlines differ from borders! Unlike border, the outline is drawn
> outside the element's border

It applies to the whole element.

You could try `box-shadow` perhaps

```css
input {outline: none; border:none; border-bottom: 1px solid orange;}
input:focus{box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 blue;}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="name">
```

Comment: Why do they have to make it so complicated, I mean why can't border-bottom work with outline: none; on input-focus. I only want lines when in focus. The amount of time I lose every time for little things like that is atrocious.  Anyway, thanks for your help! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that using **outlines**, but you can do it using **borders**.

> just Add `border-bottom` in **input field** and changed border color
> on **Hover** and **Focus**

```css
input{
/* Extra css */
height: 42px;
padding: 6px 12px;
background-color: #eee;
border-radius: 0px;

/* Actual css */
border: 0px;
outline: 0px;
border-bottom: 2px blue solid;
}

/* CSS for Hover */
input:hover{
border-bottom: 2px red solid;
}

/* CSS for Focus */ 
input:focus{
border-bottom: 2px green solid;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your Name...">
```

Answer (score 0):

the Outline CSS code has the following properties:

```
outline-style
outline-color
outline-width
outline-offset
outline
```

you can't keep the outline bottom and remove the remaining (top, left and right.) you have to keep all or remove all. but you can use border instead, like this:

```
.class-name {border-bottom: solid 2px white;}
```